# How did my submit button automatically label itself as "Create User"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

Maybe this has an easy explanation, but I am curious as to how my user `new.html.haml` submit button knows/knew to label it as "Create User" automatically within the application view?  Is this a rails convension because the action and/or route comes from UsersController and/or UserModel?

**User new.html.haml**

```
%h1 Sign up
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @user.errors.full_messages
          %li= message
  %p
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.text_field :email
  %p
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %p
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  %p.button= f.submit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a create action, it's a Rails convention for the form submit button to have the form "Create ". You an override this by adding a string after submit.

For example:

```
f.submit "Sign up"
```

Answer (score 1):

The label is generated by the form helpers `form_for`. It knows about your model (`@user`) and if it is a save or update action.

See 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9f44aa08636dfbba9261f4350ec14684425c4b7b/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1814
for the submit helper and 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9f44aa08636dfbba9261f4350ec14684425c4b7b/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1873
for how the label is created.

You can pass your own label:

```
f.submit "DO THIS NOW"
```